# Complex Analysis: Analytical Function $ f(z) ={z^{2}}/({\mathrm{e}^{x} \cos y+i \mathrm{e}^{x} \sin y})\,$?

Tags: complex-analysis, functions, cauchy-riemann-equations

**Problem**

*In which region of the complex plane is the following function analytic?*

$$f(z) = \dfrac{z^{2}}{\mathrm{e}^{x} \cos y+i \mathrm{e}^{x} \sin y}$$

*If the function has a derivative over its domain, determine $f'(z)$.*

**Progress**

First I expressed $f (z)$ as $u (x, y) + v (x, y).$

$$f(z) = \left[ \dfrac{x.\cos y + y.\sin y}{\mathrm{e}^x} + \left( \dfrac{y\cos y + x\sin y}{\mathrm{e}^x} \right) i \right],$$

$$f(z) = u(x,y) + v(x,y).$$

Then I used the Cauchy-Riemann equations

$\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x} = -\left(\cos\left(y\right)x+y\sin\left(y\right)-\cos\left(y\right)\right)\mathrm{e}^{-x}$

$\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial y} = \mathrm{e}^{-x}\left(-x\sin\left(y\right)+\sin\left(y\right)+y\cos\left(y\right)\right)$

$\dfrac{\partial v}{\partial y} = \mathrm{e}^{-x}\left(-y\sin\left(y\right)+x\cos\left(y\right)+\cos\left(y\right)\right)$

$\dfrac{\partial v}{\partial x} = -\left(\sin\left(y\right)x-\sin\left(y\right)+y\cos\left(y\right)\right)\mathrm{e}^{-x}$

then

$\begin{aligned}
&\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial v}{\partial y} \\
&\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}=-\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}
\end{aligned}$

But I don't really understand the rationale for using the Cauchy-Rieman equations in this problem, and I can't determine what the region is. I am trying to see it from the most essential aspect (using epsilon and delta, and compact sets) but I don't understand.

Comment: For analytic functions, you get basic theorems as in real-valued calculus: sum, difference, product and quotient of analytic functions is analytic. I think you can avoid Cauchy-Riemann.

Comment: Note that $f(z)=z^2 /e^z =z^2 e^{-z}$.

Answer (score 1):

Your functions $u$ and $v$ are (real) differentiable and satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann equations on the whole plane. So the function $f$ is analytic.

To find $f'(z)$, even if you don't notice that $f(z)=z^2e^{-z}$, you can just use: $f'(z) = u_x-iu_y$.